# Edge homomorphism of Leray spectral sequence is canonical.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

This question is based on *Demailly*'s note, *Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry*, IV.13.8, p.233.

$F: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $\mathscr{A}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$. For the Godement resolution $0\rightarrow \mathscr{A} \rightarrow \mathscr{A}^{[0]} \rightarrow \mathscr{A}^{[1]} \rightarrow \cdots$, we can associate a double complex $K^{p,q} = (F_\star(A^{[p]}))^{[q]}$. Consider the Leray spectral sequence of $F$. The edge homomorphism
$$H^l(Y, F_\star\mathscr{A}) \twoheadrightarrow E^{l,0}_\infty \hookrightarrow H^l(K^{[\bullet,\bullet]}) \cong H^l(F_\star(\mathscr{A}^{[\bullet]}))= H^l(X,\mathscr{A})$$
is not obviously *canonical* (This 'edge homomorphism' is actually a composite of two edge homomorphisms of two different spectral sequence). **Now for short, you can just jump down to the bottom of the question.**

However, in *Demailly*'s note, *Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry*, IV.13.8, p.233, he gives that the edge homomorphism coninsides with the composite morphism
$$F^\#: H^l(Y,F_\star\mathscr{A}) \overset{F^\star}{\longrightarrow} H^l(X,F^{-1}F_\star \mathscr{A})\overset{H^l(\mu_F)}{\longrightarrow} H^l(X,\mathscr{A})$$
where $\mu_F : F^{-1}F_\star \mathscr{A} \longrightarrow \mathscr{A}$ is the canonical sheaf morphism.

In the proof he at first construction a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^l(X,\mathscr{A}) @<<< H^l(Y,F_\star\mathscr{A})\\
@AF^\#AA @AA\mathrm{Id}A\\
H^l(Y,F_\star\mathscr{A}) @<<< H^l(Y,F_\star\mathscr{A})
\end{CD}
$$
where the upper and lower arrows are edge homomorphisms. Then we need only prove the situation where $F = \mathrm{Id}$.
And then *Demailly* says this is an immediate consequence of the fact that we have a quasi-isomorphism
$$(\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathscr{A} \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots) \longrightarrow \mathscr{A}^{[\bullet]}$$
where $\mathscr{A}^{[\bullet]}$ is the *Godement flabby resolution of $\mathscr{A}$*.

My question is why the quasi-isomorphism of resolution implies that the edge homomorphism is identity?

---

Just consider $F=\mathrm{Id}$. Let $\{E_r^{p,q}\}$ be the spectral sequence associated to filtration $K_p=\otimes_{l \ge p}K^{[l,\bullet]}$, and $\{ \tilde{E}_r^{p,q} \}$ be the spectral sequence associated to the filtration $\tilde{K}_p = \otimes_{l \ge p}K^{[\bullet , l]}$. The edge homomorphism constructed first maps $H^l(X,\mathscr{A}) = E_2^{l,0}$ into $H^l(K^{[\bullet,\bullet]})$, then maps out from $H^l(K^{[\bullet,\bullet]})$ into $\tilde{E}_2^{0,l} = H^l(X,\mathscr{A})$. What the theorem assert is that this morphism is actually identity! That's what I am confused about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has an answer in [Natural morphism appearing in Grothendieck spectral sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28827/natural-morphism-appearing-in-grothendieck-spectral-sequence). The answer involves some categorical and homologicalll algebraic argument.